# How do you fix firebase storage exceptions?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

**Hello, I am developing a Kotlin app and have been using Firebase.
However, I encountered this error:**

```
2020-08-05 00:56:45.764 9163-9296/com.example.realtimechat E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
2020-08-05 00:56:45.767 9163-9296/com.example.realtimechat E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:433)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:450)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:441)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:70)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:62)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:76)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

**I am trying to pull information from Firebase to display them on recycler view, but I do not know what I am doing wrong.**

***My Fragment:***

```
package com.example.realtimechat.findfriends

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.realtimechat.R
import com.example.realtimechat.common.Constants
import com.example.realtimechat.common.NodeNames
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.*

class FindFriendsFragment: Fragment() {

    private var rvFindFriends: RecyclerView? = null
    private var findFriendsAdapter: FindFriendAdapter? = null
    private var findFriendsModelList: MutableList<FindFriendModel> = ArrayList()
    private var tvEmptyFriendsList: TextView? = null

    private var databaseReference: DatabaseReference? = null
    private var currentUser: FirebaseUser? = null
    private var progressBar: View? = null

    private var databaseReferenceFriendRequests: DatabaseReference? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_friends, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        rvFindFriends = view.findViewById(R.id.rvFindFriends)
        tvEmptyFriendsList = view.findViewById(R.id.tvEmptyFriendsList)
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)

        rvFindFriends!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        findFriendsModelList = ArrayList()
        findFriendsAdapter = FindFriendAdapter(activity!!, findFriendsModelList)
        rvFindFriends!!.adapter = findFriendsAdapter

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(NodeNames.USERS);
        currentUser  = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser;

        databaseReferenceFriendRequests = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(NodeNames.FRIEND_REQUESTS).child(currentUser!!.uid);

        tvEmptyFriendsList!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
        progressBar!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE;

        val query: Query = databaseReference!!.orderByChild(NodeNames.USERNAME)
        query.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                findFriendsModelList.clear()

                for(ds: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                    val userId = ds.key
                    if(userId.equals(currentUser?.uid)){
                        continue
                    }

                    if(ds.child(NodeNames.USERNAME).value !=null){
                        val username = ds.child(NodeNames.USERNAME).value.toString()
                        val photoFileName = ds.child(NodeNames.PHOTO).value.toString()

                        databaseReferenceFriendRequests!!.child(userId!!).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
                            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                if(snapshot.exists()){
                                    val requestType = snapshot.child(NodeNames.REQUEST_TYPE).value.toString()
                                    if(requestType == Constants.REQUEST_STATUS_SENT){
                                        findFriendsModelList.add(FindFriendModel(userId, photoFileName, username, true))
                                        findFriendsAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    findFriendsModelList.add(FindFriendModel(userId, photoFileName, username, false))
                                    findFriendsAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                }
                            }

                            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                                progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
                            }
                        })
                        progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
                        tvEmptyFriendsList?.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to fetch friend list ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

***My Adapter:***

```
package com.example.realtimechat.findfriends

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.realtimechat.R
import com.example.realtimechat.common.Constants
import com.example.realtimechat.common.NodeNames
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage


class FindFriendAdapter(private val context: Context,
                        private val findFriendModelList: List<FindFriendModel> = mutableListOf()) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FindFriendAdapter.FindFriendViewHolder>() {


    private var friendRequestDatabase: DatabaseReference? = null
    private var currentUser: FirebaseUser? = null
    private var userId: String? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FindFriendAdapter.FindFriendViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_find_friends_layout, parent, false)
        return FindFriendViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FindFriendAdapter.FindFriendViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val friendModel = findFriendModelList[position]
        holder.tvUsername.text = friendModel.username

        val fileRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(Constants.IMAGES_FOLDER + "/" + friendModel.photoFileName)
        fileRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(uri)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profileicon)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_profileicon)
                .into(holder.ivProfile)
        }

        friendRequestDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(NodeNames.FRIEND_REQUESTS)
        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        if(friendModel.requestSent!!){
            holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }else{
            holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        holder.btnSendRequest.setOnClickListener {
            holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            userId = friendModel.userId

            friendRequestDatabase!!.child(currentUser!!.uid).child(userId!!).child(NodeNames.REQUEST_TYPE)
                .setValue(Constants.REQUEST_STATUS_SENT)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if(task.isSuccessful){
                        friendRequestDatabase!!.child(userId!!).child(currentUser!!.uid).child(NodeNames.REQUEST_TYPE)
                            .setValue(Constants.REQUEST_STATUS_RECEIVED)
                            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                if(task.isSuccessful){
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Request sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                    holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                    holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                    holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                }
                            }.addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to send request ${exception.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                            }
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to send request ${exception.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                }
        }

        holder.btnCancelRequest.setOnClickListener {
            holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            userId = friendModel.userId

            friendRequestDatabase!!.child(currentUser!!.uid).child(userId!!).child(NodeNames.REQUEST_TYPE)
                .setValue(null)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if(task.isSuccessful){
                        friendRequestDatabase!!.child(userId!!).child(currentUser!!.uid).child(NodeNames.REQUEST_TYPE)
                            .setValue(null)
                            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                if(task.isSuccessful){
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Request cancelled successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                    holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                    holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                }
                            }.addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to cancel request ${exception.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            }
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to cancel request ${exception.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return findFriendModelList.size
    }

    inner class FindFriendViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val ivProfile: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivProfilePic)
        val tvUsername: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsername)
        val btnSendRequest: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnSendRequest)
        val btnCancelRequest: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelRequest)
        val pbRequest: ProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pbRequest)

    }
}
```

***My XML File for Fragment:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".findfriends.FindFriendsFragment"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        layout="@layout/custom_progressbar"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvFindFriends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEmptyFriendsList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Friends list will appear here"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this error is from the firebase storage not from the firebase database. please check the object you trying to access is present in firebase storage or not

Comment: @HasnainSabir yes, the firebase storage code is present in my adapter class. Could you look at that and check my code because I am still not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: sir code is present but the issue is the image you are trying to access isn't available or some path issue you have.

Comment: I see; however, the only path is "images/" and with `val fileRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(Constants.IMAGES_FOLDER + "/" + friendModel.photoFileName)` I believe I am correctly pointing to that path.

Comment: do yoo log the image name and verify it. and also check the image format either it is .png or .jpg etc

Comment: @HasnainSabir I have figured out the problem. `friendModel.photoFileName` returns: `/v0/b/realtimechat-280e1.appspot.com/o/images/D7sZ9AdePTZIsniSGEIhlfSXbfD2.jpg`. However, the file name in the storage is: `D7sZ9AdePTZIsniSGEIhlfSXbfD2.jpg`. Therefore, `/v0/b/realtimechat-280e1.appspot.com/o/images/` should be deleted. Do you have any ideas how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing `404 network request` error which means that the object you are trying to access is not available in server.

```
 val fileRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(Constants.IMAGES_FOLDER + "/" + friendModel.photoFileName)

  //your firebase storage path is not available or exist please have a look on it.
```

Comment: I find that strange because on my console in Firebase (connected to this app), all the materials needed are present.

Comment: Is there any suggestions, knowing what I just said?

Comment: can you please verify this path (Constants.IMAGES_FOLDER + "/" + friendModel.photoFileName)  in your firebase storage console

Comment: please do debuging at friendModel.photoFileName

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of your firebase storage console.

Comment: Ok. friendModel is an object from a list of FriendModel data class objects. FriendModel class contains information about objects (like username and photoFileName). friendModel is assigned a variable from a certain position at the list and has the information for each "block" in the recycer view (e.g. username, photofilename).

Comment: I have just updated and added a picture of my console

Comment: could you please update it after clicking on "images" folder i need to verify it's photofileName.

Comment: I know friendModelName contains information about the user like username and photoFileName.
it's throwing an exception at some index where the filename is not present in firebase storage.
that's why I suggest you do Log at friendModelName

Comment: could you elaborate of "Log"ing at friendModelName? Sorry for the inconvenience for I am pretty new to development.

Comment: just put it Log.i("Application-Tag",friendModel.photoFileName) 
inside onBindViewHolder after      holder.tvUsername.text = friendModel.username
then Run the application and check logCatWindow with "Application-Tag"

Comment: can you please attach a screenshot of your Database as well where the photoFileName are placed.

Comment: @Jeremy if you just need to show the images then you don't need to access it using firebase storage you just access it using Photo node in firebase db just like that.
just remove the firebase storage line and pass the photo url into glide
 Glide.with(context)
                .load(friendModel.photoFileName)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profileicon)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_profileicon)
                .into(holder.ivProfile)

Comment: you got exception due to some Photos have empty value and some photos have a URL link, not a photo file name while you are accessing it using the file name.

Comment: sorry for the late response, but no, I alway need to display the username, and other variables as well

Comment: you can use it 
Glide.with(context) .load(friendModel.photoFileName) .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profileicon) .error(R.drawable.ic_profileicon) .into(holder.ivProfile)

Comment: The code did remove the exception error from occurring. However, it failed to show the images. The error was that it was unable to find the file. I have brought down the number of users to two and had one user have a picture and the other have no picture. Using the user without a picture, I saw an blue colored text that said: `Load failed for /v0/b/realtimechat-280e1.appspot.com/o/images/D7sZ9AdePTZIsniSGEIhlfSXbfD2.jpg `. However, in the database, the image file name is: `"/v0/b/realtimechat-280e1.appspot.com/o/images/D7sZ9AdePTZIsniSGEIhlfSXbfD2.jpg"` which is exactly identical..

Comment: Therefore, I do not see a reason why it failed to find the file when the names are identical

Comment: I have figured out the problem. `friendModel.photoFileName` returns: `/v0/b/realtimechat-280e1.appspot.com/o/images/D7sZ9AdePTZIsniSGEIhlfSXbfD2.jpg`. However, the file name in the storage is: `D7sZ9AdePTZIsniSGEIhlfSXbfD2.jpg`. Therefore, `/v0/b/realtimechat-280e1.appspot.com/o/images/` should be deleted. Do you have any ideas how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue.

Looking at the adapter file (where the error occured),
I found out that friendModel.photoFileName returns:

```
/v0/b/realtimechat-280e1.appspot.com/o/images/D7sZ9AdePTZIsniSGEIhlfSXbfD2.jpg
```

However, the file name in the storage is:

```
D7sZ9AdePTZIsniSGEIhlfSXbfD2.jpg
```

Therefore, the file name was incorrect, thus the image was unable to be displayed. In order for this issue to be gone, `/v0/b/realtimechat-280e1.appspot.com/o/images/` should be removed from
`/v0/b/realtimechat-280e1.appspot.com/o/images/D7sZ9AdePTZIsniSGEIhlfSXbfD2.jpg` so that only `D7sZ9AdePTZIsniSGEIhlfSXbfD2.jpg` remains. So I did `requestModel.photoFileName!!.substring(requestModel.photoFileName!!.lastIndexOf("/")+1)`, which means that I only keep the parts of String **after** the last `/`, so only `D7sZ9AdePTZIsniSGEIhlfSXbfD2.jpg` remains.

**The final code:** `val fileRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(Constants.IMAGES_FOLDER + "/" + friendModel.photoFileName!!.substring(friendModel.photoFileName!!.lastIndexOf("/")+1))`

`fileRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {uri -> Glide.with(context).load(uri).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profileicon).error(R.drawable.ic_profileicon).into(holder.ivProfile)}`

I am not certain if this code works for all cases, so if you have a better solution to this, it would be best for you to post it. Thank you